# Inclusion for pairwise disjoint sets and $\limsup A_n = \emptyset$

Tags: measure-theory

Spin-off from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856238/140308).

1 Please give an example of how the following does not hold for a collection that is not pairwise disjoint.

$$ \bigcup_{k \ge n+1} A_k = A\setminus (A_1 \cup\cdots \cup A_n) $$

2 Does anyone have any references for $\limsup A_n = \emptyset$ if $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a pairwise disjoint collection?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to use the definition of $\limsup A_n$ for $2$...?

Comment: To anyone with the same question: You can also try any ascending or descending sequence of sets. That might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.) take $A_{i}=[\frac{-1}{i},\frac{1}{i}]$. We see that 
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}=[-1,1]=A$$
From this we have that 
$$\bigcup_{k\geq n+1}^{\infty}A_{k}=[\frac{-1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+1}]$$
but [
$$A\backslash(A_{1}\cup...\cup A_{n})=A\backslash A=\emptyset$$
which is do to fact $A_{1}=[-1,1]$

Answer (score 0):

Or consider any ascending or descending set. That is, $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1} or A_n \supseteq A_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. I like @user159813's answer better though.