# Disprove counterexample for $\limsup A_n = \emptyset$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a pairwise disjoint collection.

$\lim A_n = \emptyset$? (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856223/given-a-pairwise-disjoint-collection-limsup-a-n-emptyset) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863948/given-a-pairwise-disjoint-collection-liminf-a-n-emptyset))

What about a set of extended real numbers $A_n=(n,n+1]$?

It seems that

$\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n$

$= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} (n, n+1]$

$= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} ((k, k+1] \cup (k+1, k+2] \cup ...)$

$= \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} ((k, \infty])$

... = {$\infty$} ?

Comment: Note that $\infty\not\in (n,n+1]$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $\infty\not\in \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty (n,n+1]$.

Comment: Note that $\infty$ is not an element of $\cup_{n=k}^\infty(n,n+1]$ for any $k$.

Comment: @Brandon Are you saying that the penultimate step is incorrect?

Comment: @Chellapillai Are you saying that the penultimate step is incorrect?

Comment: @BCLC: Yes.${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\infty$ is not in those unions (i.e., it is not in $\bigcup\limits_{n=k}^\infty(n,n+1]$ for any $k$), because it is not in any of the individual sets being unioned (i.e., it is not in $(n,n+1]$ for any $n$).

Comment: Wait I think I get it. Is it for the same reason the union here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity#An_additive_function_which_is_not_.CF.83-additive is (0,1) instead of [0,1)?

Comment: @BCLC: Yes. In that case, every positive number is eventually in the sets, but $0$ is not in any of them, so it is not in their union.

Comment: @BCLC: I rolled back the edit which was incorrect, but will try to edit for greater clarity in a bit.