# Lemma about probability space P (From Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability-theory

This is from Grimmett and Stirzaker, Chapter 1, page 7.

> **Lemma**. Let $A_{1},A_{2},...$ be an increasing sequence of events, so that $A_{1}\subseteq{A_{2}}\subseteq{A_{3}}\subseteq{...}$, and write A for their limit:
>
> $A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_{i}}=\lim_{i\to\infty}{A_{i}}$
>
> Then, $P(A)=\lim_{i\to\infty}{P(A_{i})}$
>
> **Proof.**
>
> $A={A_{1}}\cup({A_{2}-A_{1}})\cup({A_{3}-A_{2}})\cup{...}$ is a disjoint union of sets. Thus, by definition,
>
> $P(A) = P({A_{1}})+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P({A_{i+1}}\setminus{A_{i}})$
>
> $P(A) = P({A_{1}})+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(P({A_{i+1}})-P({A_{i}}))$
>
> $P(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(A_{n})}$

Whilst I understand the math behind the proof, what are we trying to prove here. Why would be interested in such an increase sequence of events? What good is this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples:

1. Used in the proof of $P(\liminf A_n) \le \liminf P(A_n) \le \limsup P(A_n)  \le P(\limsup A_n):$

$$P(\liminf (A_n)) = \lim_{N \to \infty}P(\bigcap_{n \ge N} A_n)$$

---

2. Uniqueness of conditional expectation (Williams' Probability w/ Martingales)

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

3. From Rosenthal's book:

---

[image]

---

4. [A property of independence of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1361962/140308)

---

[image]

---

5. [Continuity of 'measure' proves countable additivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448605/continuity-together-with-finite-additivity-implies-countable-additivity):

---

[image]

---

6. [Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907227/continuity-of-measure-and-integration)

[image]